# How to fix : 'Received error from connectors' with Microsoft Teams

Tags: c#, razor, microsoft-teams

I am developing a custom connector to teams in a personnal app. When I save it I have this error : "Unable to save "" connector configuration", 
 and this in Console : 
[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BraSl.png)
I followed the Microsoft sample, here it's the setup.cshtml :

```
"microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler(function (saveEvent) {
    microsoftTeams.getContext(function (context) {
        url = "https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/Connector/Setup.cshtml";
        entity = 'connector-officedev-' + context.teamId + '-' + context.channelId;

        microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
            entityId: entity,
            contentUrl: url,
            configName: entity
        });
    });
    microsoftTeams.settings.getSettings(function (settings) {
        //var webhookUrl = settings.webhookUrl;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Save',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data:  JSON.stringify({ urlwebhook :settings.webhookUrl }),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#webhookUrl").text(data);
                console.log('webhook created successfully.');
            },
            error: function (errorThrown) {
                $("#webhookUrl").text("Error");
                console.log('error', errorThrown);
            }
        });

    });

    saveEvent.notifySuccess();
});
microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnRemoveHandler(function (removeEvent) {
    var removeCalled = true;
});"
```

I had "https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/Connector/Setup.cshtml", in Valid Domains in Connectors Developer Dashboard
I Don't know why it isn't working
Thanks for your help

**UPDATE 1**
On the first clic on "Save", there is the error, but on the second clic it's working, and I can send a message to the webhook

**UPDATE SOLUTION**
I find the solution, the saveEvent.notifySucess(); must be in the success function of the ajax call, like that :

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'Save',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data:  JSON.stringify({ urlwebhook :settings.webhookUrl }),
        success: function (data) {
            $("#webhookUrl").text(data);
            console.log('webhook created successfully.');
            saveEvent.notifySuccess();
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            $("#webhookUrl").text("Error");
            console.log('error', errorThrown);
            saveEvent.notifyFailure("error");
        }
    });
```

You also need to place a notifySuccess in the RemoveHandler like that :

```
microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnRemoveHandler(function (removeEvent) {
    var removeCalled = true;
    removeEvent.notifySuccess();
});
```

Comment: From what you wrote, I assume this is running on Azure? If you are on the free tier, are you sure the server is awake? One thing we usually do is create a default route so that https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/ returns a simple default web page. Try loading that web page and then try your connector - if it works right away, that's the problem.

Comment: Thank for your answer ,Yes it's running on Azure, and not on the free tier, it's running on the azure subscription of my company, and the server is awake because when I go on mydomain.azurewebsites.net it returns the default web page

Comment: OK. Do you really have the entire URL in validDomains? It should only be "mydomain.azurewebsites.net". On the other hand that wouldn't cause your problem. Is your code even being called? Have you tried running the code locally via ngrok where it's easier to diagnose?

Comment: I put : "https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net" in valid domain. I can't run the code via ngrok because port are close for security. But I sure the code is call because the ajax call in the getSettings() is call, moreover on the second clic on save (after the first which throw the error) the webhook is save and I can send a message on it, I don't understand why there is an error on the first call

Comment: I find the solution, look at the Update Solution, thanks for the answers